# Database Design Questions on Unnecessary Foreign Keys

Tags: database-design

Let's say I have three tables - `Applicants`, `Groups`, and `Seasons`. Each `Applicant` has a `group` and each `group` has a `season`.

On the other side each `season` has multiple `groups` and each `group` has multiple `applicants`.

Is there anything wrong from a performance perspective or for that matter from any other one to link `Applicant` to both `Group` and `Season` directly, even though you can get to `season` through it's `group`.

Comment: @downvoter & closevoter : it's a question about database design.  Database design is not exact science.  Do you intend to disallow just any question about database design here in the future ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might win an unnoticeable bit of time in read mode, because one less join to do, and you certainly win an update anomaly, which will significantly complicate life (coding) for you when updating the database, and which will almost certainly deteriorate performance very very noticeably when a Group "changes Season".

(And if Groups never "change Season", then you probably shouldn't be having Season in your database altogether.)

Comment: Groups never change season, but we need to be easily able to generate reports by season , if i elimianted season and added it as a column to groups it wouldnt be as easy to do this correct?

Comment: What do you mean "added it as a column to groups" ?  If your database design accurately reflects the notion that "each group has a season", then that column should already be there.  You don't need the Season table to be there in order to make Group reports per season.  (If you have some kind of reporting tool that does demand this, then you should indicate this in your question, because then the question is no longer merely about database design.)

Comment: i meant that in the groups table i would track the season name, so how much you run such a query without a seasons table i would query the groups table first and group by season and from there proceed.